# Regex to find and replace where the Key is the same as Value {foo:foo} to {foo}

Tags: regex, regex-group

Summary:
Use regex with place holders to find where the key and value are the same, and replace with just the key (in my case leveraging ES6 object-property shorthand syntax to clean thousands lines of broken ES5 code - where I can't find an auto helper in eslint rules for use with --fix).

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar,
    baz: someFunctionNotCalledBaz,
    someOther: () => console.log('Defined directly. Not a reference to same name function.')
};
```

What I want (cleaning up old, broken code and ES6'ing a NodeJS project):

```
module.exports = {
    foo,
    bar,
    baz: someFunctionNotCalledBaz,
    someOther: () => console.log('Defined directly. Not a reference to same name function.')
};
```

I'm pretty familiar with regex, and I'm not sure this is even be possible. Using Vim, or an IDE Replace w/ regex I'd like to find a way to say:

Find all "word: word", regardless of spaces, and then the matching key on the value side:

`(\w+)(:{1}\s{0,})(*SOMEHOW_REFERENCE_FIRST_MATCHING_GROUP_WITHIN_FIND*)`

Replace with reference (using placeholder that would already work with matching group):

`$1`

Is this "lookback" even possible within the same regex? I did look at a bunch of other posts that matched my query, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean like this using a backreference? `(\w+):\s+\1`  https://regex101.com/r/WoFBGe/1

Comment: This could get a bit complicated because keys can be quote-delimited and contain arbitrary information in them. For example, `{"foo: foo": foo}` is a valid object. Can you describe all of the edge cases you expect to encounter?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```sh
sed -E 's/(.+): \1/\1/g' file
```

If you're unfamiliar with `sed`, the first part will look for strings that match the pattern `(.+): \1`, and the second part will replace it with `\1`

The `\1` you see are backreferences, they refer to a capturing group. A capturing group is text inside parenthesis (here, `(.+)`).

`(.+): \1` will locate any string of 1 or more characters followed by a semicolon and a space, and then the same string again.

And finally, `sed` will replace any matching string with `\1`, which is the part before the semicolon.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: So awesome! I'll point out: `-E` = Extended regex. Without it the backreference is Illegal. I also added `-i` so that the operation directly changes the file in-place.
Super great addition to my cleaner script. This will go just after unquoting keys!
`sed -ri 's/("{1})(\w+)(":{1})/\2:/g' $1` BTW, I couldn't `-Ei` (combine flags in the working answer).